# Meu do while não tem fim

Tags: c, do-while

Estou fazendo uma calculadora. O programa executa operações dependendo do numero que o usuário escolher.

O problema é que ao digitar 5 é pra encerrar o laço e isso não está acontecendo.

```c
    int main(void){
    float x,y;
    int operador;
    do{
        printf("\n\nEscolha a operacao:");
        printf("\n\t1-SOMA\n\t2-SUBTRACAO\n\t3-MULTIPLICACAO\n\t4-DIVISAO\n\t5-SAIR\n");
        scanf("%d",&operador);
        printf("Primeiro numero:");
        scanf("%f",&x);
        printf("Segundo numero:");
        scanf("%f",&y);
        switch(operador){
            case 1:
                printf("RESULTADO:%0.2f",x+y);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("RESULTADO:%0.2f",x-y);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("RESULTADO:%0.2f",x*y);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("RESULTADO:%0.2f",x/y);
                break;
        }
    }while(operador!=5);
    printf("...Voce encerrou a calculadora...");
}
```

Comment: Aqui finalizou. Em inseri o valor 5, ele pediu os valores do primeiro e segundo números, como esperado e depois finalizou o laço de repetição. O que acontece quando você coloca o 5?

Comment: Ele começa novamente, pede pra indicar a operação e os dois numeros

Comment: Ele começa novamente ou só continua a execução como deveria? Pois depois que você lê o valor de `operador` você sempre lerá o valor de `x` e `y`, independente do valor de `operador`. Se digitar 5 para `operador` e quaisquer valores para `x` e `y` o programa irpa encerrar como esperado. Não era esse o comportamento que desejava?

Comment: Aqui pra mim, quando digito 5 para ooperador e qualquer valor para x e y, ele não encerra. Era pra ele mostrar o ultimo printf do código e finalizar, isso não acontece

Answer (score 2):

Acho que você quer que funcione assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    float x,y;
    int operador;
    do{
        printf("\n\nEscolha a operacao:");
        printf("\n\t1-SOMA\n\t2-SUBTRACAO\n\t3-MULTIPLICACAO\n\t4-DIVISAO\n\t5-SAIR\n");
        scanf("%d",&operador);
        if(operador>0 && operador<=4){
            printf("Primeiro numero:");
            scanf("%f",&x);
            printf("Segundo numero:");
            scanf("%f",&y);
            switch(operador){
            case 1:
                printf("RESULTADO:%0.2f",x+y);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("RESULTADO:%0.2f",x-y);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("RESULTADO:%0.2f",x*y);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("RESULTADO:%0.2f",x/y);
                break;
            }
        }
    }while(operador!=5);
    printf("...Voce encerrou a calculadora...");
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens a alternativa de implementar um **`case 5:`** com um **`continue`**.

Fica a opção de usar com ou sem o **`do while`**, funciona nas duas formas...

```
        case 5:
            printf("...Voce encerrou a calculadora...");
            continue;
        }
}
```

> ou ..

```
        case 4:
            printf("RESULTADO:%0.2f",x/y);
            break;
        case 5:
            continue;
        }

    }while(operador!=5);
    printf("...Voce encerrou a calculadora...");
}
```